# Arrays and strings not being resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to edit an array by using a method. I've cut out a lot of my code to try and isolate the part that I can't get to work.

```
import java.util.*;
public class moretesting {
   public static void shift() {
      for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
          arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
          if (arr[i] > 126) {
              arr[i] = arr[i] - 95;
          } else if (arr[i] < 32) {
              arr[i] = arr[i] + 95;
          }
      }
  }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String message = "abc";
      int arr[] = new int[message.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = message.charAt(i);
        }
   shift();
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
   } 
}
```

I'm getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: message cannot be resolved
arr cannot be resolved to a variable (This one repeats multiple times)
at moretesting.shift(moretesting.java:4)
at moretesting.main(moretesting.java:19)"

I'm fairly certain that this has something to do with the scope of my variables, but I can't figure it out. This is also my first post here, so I'm sorry if the formatting isn't the best.

Comment: `arr` and `message` are not defined in the `shift` function. Look up "parameters" and "return values"

Comment: Pass the `arr` and `message` in `shift` function or declare them in public scope

Comment: Those two variables are defined in the scope of the `main` method, but they are never declared anywhere in the `shift` method. Define shift as `public static void shift(String message, int[] arr)` and call `shift` inside `main` like this: `shift(message, arr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: The variables **arr** and **message** should be **static**

```
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    static int arr[];        // This declare
    static String message;   // This declare

    public static void shift() {
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
            if (arr[i] > 126) {
                arr[i] = arr[i] - 95;
            } else if (arr[i] < 32) {
                arr[i] = arr[i] + 95;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        message = "abc";
        arr = new int[message.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = message.charAt(i);
        }
        shift();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}`
```

Solution 2: Pass arguments on method

```
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    public static void shift(int arr[], String message) {
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
            if (arr[i] > 126) {
                arr[i] = arr[i] - 95;
            } else if (arr[i] < 32) {
                arr[i] = arr[i] + 95;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "abc";
        int arr[] = new int[message.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = message.charAt(i);
        }
        shift(arr, message); // This pass arguments
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually did try to add the variables at the beginning, but obviously did it wrong and then accidentally redeclared them later on. I'm sorry for not knowing how to use Stack Overflow, but how do I close this question (or is that even a thing)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `arr` and `message` as arguments to `shift()` function

```java
import java.util.*;
public class moretesting {
   public static void shift(String message, int[] arr) {
      for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
          arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
          if (arr[i] > 126) {
              arr[i] = arr[i] - 95;
          } else if (arr[i] < 32) {
              arr[i] = arr[i] + 95;
          }
      }
  }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "abc";
        int arr[] = new int[message.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = message.charAt(i);
        }
        shift(message, arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
   } 
}
```

Comment: `shift` is working on the same array as `main`, so there's no need to return it.